# what do we use to define externals in webpack2?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2

I am trying to migrate an existing project from webpack 1 to webpack 2, I have been able to do it for the most part but not sure how we define externals in webpack 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple to use official doc paragraph Externals:

Example from doc:

```
externals : {
  lodash : {
    commonjs: "lodash",
    amd: "lodash",
    root: "_" // indicates global variable
  }
}
```